# Cisco IPSec Hardware Requirements

Tags: cisco, router, ipsec, hardware

In order to use IPSec on 2811 and 2651XM Cisco routers, does one need any particular hardware module(s) or just the appropriate software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Advanced Enterpise Services or Advanced Security IOS on the 2811 router to create IPSEC tunnels.

Check Cisco Feature Navigator for more details.

Answer (score 3):

No special hardware modules are required. As long as you have a K9 image with IPsec support, you can establish an IPsec tunnel. However, the crypto transforms are CPU-intensive, so router performance may suffer without dedicated hardware. Whether you need it really depends on what you're doing with the router.

On the 2600XM series, hardware VPN acceleration is provided by one of the [AIM-VPN](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/12_2z/12_2zj/feature/guide/gtaimvpn.html) add-on modules. If you have one installed, it should show up in the output of `show diag`.

On the 2811, hardware VPN acceleration is built-in:

```
c2811#show diag
Slot 0:
        C2811 Motherboard with 2FE and integrated VPN Port adapter, 2 ports
                       ...

c2811#show crypto engine configuration
        crypto engine name:  Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
        crypto engine type:  hardware
                     State:  Enabled
                       ...
```

There isn't anything needed in order to enable it. IOS will automatically use it for any DES, 3DES, or AES CBC transforms.